# SparkPost suppression error and mail stops sending

Tags: django, sparkpost

I am using SparkPost for one of my Django website to send mails to users.
I had an update on site so sending mails to all users.

However few of users have deleted their Gmail id from Gmail and I understand that mails cannot be sent to those ids.

However problem I am facing is that in Django, SparkPost stops sending mails to all users once a single mail fails because of this.

Error message is this:

```
Message generation rejected Code: 1902 Description: recipient address was suppressed due to system policy
```

Answer (score 0):

That specific error `...suppressed due to system policy` is SparkPost saying that it decided not to send to a particular recipient address because it appears on its Global Suppression List. You can [read about it here](https://www.sparkpost.com/docs/deliverability/global-suppression-list/) but basically, no-one should send email to addresses on that list so SparkPost rejects mail for them to avoid an later reputation damage.

That issue alone shouldn't stop all mail from flowing though. Here are a few other options to check out which would have that effect:

- What error does SparkPost produce for the other failing messages?
- Has your account been suspended? [Log in to check](https://app.sparkpost.com).
- Does your API key have correct privileges?

As an aside, you could also ask this question on the [SparkPost Community Slack team](http://slack.sparkpost.com).

Comment: My all other mails stops once one email is suppressed. How do I make sure that mail ids not suppressed receive the mails and operation does not stop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your mailing list prior to sending out mass mailings. This will weed out stale and unreachable emails to prevent bounce in the first place.

If you are using SparkPost lists, you can just use MailboxValidator to import and clean your list for you.

https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/resources/articles/how-to-import-email-list-from-sparkpost/

If you're not using SparkPost lists, you can dump out your mailing list and just upload into MailboxValidator for cleaning then you can just import the cleaned list back into your system.